# How to transform Y axis from absolute frequency to percentage (%)

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I want to transform absolute frequency to percentage (0%-100%), however in my chart I see numbers like 70000%, etc. I also want to show % on each stacked area, e.g. bar1 -> 35% vs 65%, etc.

```
def to_percent(y, position):
    s = str(100 * y)
    if matplotlib.rcParams['text.usetex'] is True:
        return s + r'$\%$'
    else:
        return s + '%'

filter = df["CLUSTER"] == 1
plt.ylabel("Percentage")
plt.hist([df["HOUR"][filter],df["HOUR"][~filter]],stacked=True,
         color=['#8A2BE2', '#EE3B3B'], label=['1','0'])
plt.legend()

formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)

# Set the formatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

SMALL DUMMY DATASET:

```
s_hour = pd.Series(["5","5","5","8","8","9","10"]) 
s_cluster = pd.Series(["1","1","0","1","0","1","0"])  

df = pd.concat([s_hour, s_cluster], axis=1)
df
```

Comment: We have no idea what ```df``` looks like, can you provide a simplify your question and just provide the relevant information, maybe a couple of short arrays to plot,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @wwi: Updated. Sorry, I thought that this question is straightforward without  a dataset.

Comment: Yep, maybe I spoke too soon.  Your data is text?

Comment: @wwi: No, the data can be converted to numeric values, but originally it comes as string values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set plt.hist's normed paramater to True to normalize the data.

```
plt.hist([df["HOUR"][filter],df["HOUR"][~filter]],stacked=True, normed = True,
         color=['#8A2BE2', '#EE3B3B'], label=['1','0'])
```

Can't comment on your `rcParams` conditional in the format function - but this format string works - `'{:3.1%}'`.

See if this is what you want:

```
def to_percent(y, p):
    return '{:3.1%}'.format(y)

s_hour = pd.Series(["5","5","5","8","8","9","10"]) 
s_cluster = pd.Series(["1","1","0","1","0","1","0"])  

df = pd.concat([s_hour.astype(np.int32), s_cluster.astype(np.int32)], axis=1)
df.columns = ["HOUR", "CLUSTER"]
filter = df["CLUSTER"] == 1
plt.ylabel("Percentage")
plt.hist([df["HOUR"][filter],df["HOUR"][~filter]],stacked=True, normed = True,
         color=['#8A2BE2', '#EE3B3B'], label=['1','0'])
plt.legend()

formatter = FuncFormatter(to_percent)

# Set the formatter
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]